# Matlab estimate time it takes to save to disk

Tags: matlab, undocumented-behavior

Simple question:

is there any (undocumented?) way to estimate (ballpark) how long it will take for Matlab to save a single, very big variable from workspace to disk, sort of like Windows would for file transfers?

Thanks

Comment: Write N files, timing the operation, multiply time already spent by (bytes remaining)/(bytes written) for estimated time remaining. There is no way to have a general rule for this because it depends on the hardware, software, data type...

Comment: Questions was unclear, it's about one single, large workspace variable, obviously this will depend on bytes remaining and time spent on bytes already written. If e.g. a Java process can monitor this process, an estimate could be made... an expert community would know?

Comment: That's a pretty different question, it would be helpful if you edited your question to reflect what you actually want to achieve, what your use-case is, why you're currently limited (i.e. you don't know how to check a file size concurrently with actually writing the file) and additional details which might help. Currently your whole question is "show me the code for a file writing progress bar"

Comment: I don't think the question substantially changed if you assume 1 big vs several small files. The question is answerable without code, since obviously it's a conceptual question: 'Can it be done? If so, what would be the idea'. IMHO, compared to actual code requests this does not exclude very 'creative ideas'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought. You could use tic and toc to measure the save times for increasingly large variables or arrays and plot a trend graph of save time versus variable size.

Comment: This could go somewhere, especially if you think of an 'automated solution'. If the save function actually tracks the time it takes to save files locally, a reasonable guess should be possible